# Need Legislative District Lookups for CiviCRM/WordPress

Tags: wordpress, extension

I've been using CiviCRM for WordPress for a few months now. We need to be able to populate both state and federal district fields. I found some relevant links.

https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-congressional-districts-module
https://developers.google.com/civic-information/

Sounds like there are extensions out there but all for Drupal? Please tell me there's one for WordPress???

I've been a geek all my life, but never got into web-based programming or PHP.

Thanks much...Jim

Answer (score 8):

The [Electoral API](https://github.com/josephlacey/com.jlacey.electoral) extension is what you're looking for.

Comment: Hey Jon, any progress on this? thanks...jim

Comment: Hi Jim - Any day now, we need to squelch a few pre-beta bugs and write initial documentation!  If you're really itching for it...http://git.palantetech.coop/palante/civicrm/extensions/coop.palantetech.electoral/

Comment: Hey Jon, what's the status on this extension? Thanks...

Comment: @jimcrist See the link above - this got overhauled last year with support for new APIs and new functionality.

Comment: Hi Jon.  Yes, sadly I can't get V2 to work.  Please see: https://github.com/josephlacey/com.jlacey.electoral/issues/7.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

Jim, what org are you with, are you on VAN, and involved with a civic engagement table? If so send me a private message. Also check out Progressive Technology Project's implementation of Cicero. See
http://network.progressivetech.org/node/975

Comment: The Cicero extension is Drupal-only, unfortunately.

Comment: It's a new non-partisan, grassroots organization. We're not on VAN.

Answer (score 0):

What is everyone doing now that Sunlight's API is dead? OpenStates has one that is active, but I'm not familiar with how to link into it.

Comment: I need to know too...we need this extension! It used to work, but now, when I run the process to add state representative districts to contacts, I get:

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/scwmta/wiuta.org/wp-content/civicrm/extensions/electoral/api/v3/SfOpenStates.php on line 303

I found this article, which indicates the API is still working:

https://www.propublica.org/nerds/item/sunlight-labs-takeover-update

I have a Sunlight API key. Jon Goldberg has left Palante Tech, but Joseph Lacey is the Project Manager https://hq.palantetech.coop/users/5